# how to find a string is present in set of HTML tags.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have a series of images, have a variable with img URL.

Now i like to find which HTML element has that img URL as src and want to add a class to it

HTML Code

```
<ul id='carousel_ul'>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/thumbnails/image1.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/thumbnails/image2.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/thumbnails/image3.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery Code

```
temp = images/thumbnails/image2.jpg
    $("#carousel_ul").find(temp)
```

Trying to do the above, it is returning me an error

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: images/thumbnails/image2.jpg
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an attribute selector :

```
var temp = "images/thumbnails/image2.jpg";
var $elements = $('#carousel_ul img[src="'+temp+'"]')
```

or [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) :

```
var $elements = $('#carousel_ul img').filter(function(){
    return this.src==temp;
});
```